# State not Updating on React from

Tags: reactjs, forms

I have written a form in gatsby where I am unable to update the input value.

Need assistance while working on a form with gatsby I am trying to create a form to host on netlify forms.

I have added the code block below let me know if you need more information.

```
const ContactPage = () => {

const [formState, setFormState] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
  })

const handleChange = (e) => {
    setFormState({
      ...formState,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    })
  }

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
}

return (
<form
 onSubmit={handleSubmit}
 name="contact"
 method="post"
 
>  
   <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="name"
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={formState.name}
          placeholder="Enter your name"
        />
        <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
        <input
          type="email"
          id="email"
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={formState.email}
          placeholder="Enter your email"
        />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
)

}
```

Input field is not updating

- When I type in the name or email address nothing gets updated in the input field

Answer (score 0):

because you are using `id="email"` in input. But you use `name` to update state: `[e.target.name]: e.target.value`.

You just change `id="email"` to `name="email"` and `id="name"` to `name="name"`

Answer (score 0):

You use the e.target.name and it is good idea to use. But you didn't fill the name of "input" I added name into every input form

```
const { useState } = require('react');

const ContactPage = () => {
  const [formState, setFormState] = useState({
    name: '',
    email: '',
  });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.name, e.target.value);
    setFormState((formState) => ({
      ...formState,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    }));
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} name='contact' method='post'>
      <label htmlFor='name'>Name</label>
      <input
        type='text'
        id='name'
        name='name'
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={formState.name}
        placeholder='Enter your name'
      />
      <label htmlFor='email'>Email</label>
      <input
        type='email'
        id='email'
        name='email'
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={formState.email}
        placeholder='Enter your email'
      />
      <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default ContactPage;
```